# How do I stop certain words turning into Russian

Tags: cyrillic, alphabet

I am using the `[utf8]{inputenc}` and `[russian]{babel}` and this allows me to input certain Cyrillic characters easily, but it is also turning certain titles where I have used commands like `\tableofcontents`, `\abstract` and `\date{\today}` into Cyrillic form too. I can, for instance, change the `\today` command to read `\date{01/11/2012}`, which does fix the problem, but it still stops me from using certain useful commands, like the ones mentioned above.

I have set out in a table two alphabets: the Latin version, with the corresponding Cyrillic equivalents.

E.g. (Latin on the left, Cyrillic on the right)

A a - A a

B b - Б б

C c - Ц ц

...

Z z - З з

Comment: use `[russian,english]` the last listed language is the default and used for fixed strings. You can still switch between russian and english using babel features/

Comment: Would you please add an example of code, stating more clearly what you want in cyrillic and what in latin characters?

Comment: I've done this, but I get an error, it's because I had previously copy and pasted the Cyrillic characters I needed and now they don't work. I do I insert the Cyrillic characters using this package?

Comment: @egreg I've given an example now.

Comment: @DangerFourpence That's not an example, sorry. What's the main language of the document?

Comment: @egreg the main language of the document is English, the alphabet will more or less be the only use of Cyrillic in the document

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set the main language to English; with only `\usepackage[russian]{babel}` you're setting the main language to Russian, which is inadequate for typesetting English text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{ŝ}{\^{s}} % handy shortcut

\begin{document}
\author{Danger Fourpence}
\title{The cyrillic alphabet}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\section{The alphabet}

This is the Russian alphabet
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{>{\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont}ll@{\qquad}}>{\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont}ll}
{Аа} & a & {Бб} & b & {Вв} & v & {Гг} & g & {Дд} & d & {Ее} & e \\
{Ёё} & ë & {Жж} & ž & {Зз} & z & {Ии} & i & {Йй} & j & {Кк} & k \\
{Лл} & l & {Мм} & m & {Нн} & n & {Оо} & o & {Пп} & p & {Рр} & r \\
{Сс} & s & {Тт} & t & {Уу} & u & {Фф} & f & {Хх} & h & {Цц} & c \\
{Чч} & č & {Шш} & š & {Щщ} & ŝ & {Ъъ} & $''$ & {Ыы} & y & {Ьь} & $'$ \\
{Ээ} & è & {Юю} & û & {Яя} & â 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For small excerpts in Russian, use `\foreignlanguage{russian}{Москва}` or the `otherlanguage*` environment for paragraphs in Russian.